# Copy const struct in flash to "normal" struct in RAM

Tags: c, struct, copy, constants

Here is what I have, and there is still a problem - the compiler doesn't recognize the "my_reg" structure type.

../Source/functions.c:609:16: error: 'my_reg' undeclared (first use in this function)
 ModBusIDReg = (my_reg)const_ModBusIDReg;

```
// define structure in flash with constants

struct
{
  const unsigned char Reg00[32];
  const unsigned char Reg01[32];
  const unsigned char Reg02[32];
  const unsigned short Reg03;
  const unsigned short Reg04;
} const_ModBusIDReg =
{
  "My String 1" ,
  "My String 2" ,
  "My String 3" ,
   0 ,
   0
};


// define structure in RAM, tag name "my_reg"

struct my_reg
{
  unsigned char Reg00[32];
  unsigned char Reg01[32];
  unsigned char Reg02[32];
  unsigned short Reg03;
  unsigned short Reg04;
} ModBusIDReg;


// This statement is located in InitSys function.
// Both of the files where the structures were
// defined are included at the top of the file 
// where InitSys function resides.
// Make a copy of const_ModBusIDReg from
// flash into ModBusIDReg in RAM.


ModBusIDReg = (my_reg)const_ModBusIDReg;
```

Any ideas on how to do the direct assignment ?

Comment: `memcpy()` is the appropriate, efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A type cast like this should resolve the compiler error:

```
ModBusIDReg = (my_reg)const_ModBusIDReg;
```

Or you could use [memcpy()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy):

```
memcpy(&ModBusIDReg, &const_ModBusIDReg, sizeof(my_reg));
```

(Sidenote at using memcpy(): In some cases, memory alignment might be an issue. But I'm no c expert. Using [compiler-specific attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) like *packed* in the case of GCC might help, when you define the struct, depending on the platform, compiler, variable types used.)

You can also copy the members of the struct individually in a custom copy function, and initialize the unused parts if there are any. This would be clean, and very clear/explicit, and similar to a copy constructor / assignment operator used in C++ (deep copies are handled properly).

---

edit:
Since I can't add a comment above after your last edit, I add the comment here:

> ./Source/functions.c:609:16: error: 'my_reg' undeclared (first use in
>   this function) ModBusIDReg = (my_reg)const_ModBusIDReg;

In C you can use *typedef* in your struct type declartions, in order to avoid repeating the *struct* keyword throughout your code (explained in detail over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c) or [there](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct)):

```
typedef struct { ... } foo;
foo x;
```

Here an example illustrating the mentioned ideas from above:

```
/* gcc -Wall -o copy_test copy_test.c && ./copy_test */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int var;
} my_struct;

int my_copy_func(my_struct *dst, const my_struct *src)
{
    if (!dst || !src)
        return -1;
    dst->var = src->var;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    const my_struct a = { .var = 42 };
    my_struct b, c, d;
    c = (my_struct)a;
    memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(b));
    my_copy_func(&d, &a);
    printf("b.var = %d\r\n", b.var);
    printf("c.var = %d\r\n", c.var);
    printf("d.var = %d\r\n", d.var);
    return 0;
}
```